# How to pass 'pk' or some id dynamically with api call in react

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-router

I'm tring to make a edit invoice button which when called opens a form in and let users edit its choices which further gets saved in database but I cannot figure out how to pass the 'pk' with my url. For example form with pk id 1  is of user 1 and when I call api it should specificly change the invoice of user ID 1.

```
import {
   Button, Card,
   CardBody,
   CardHeader, Col, Form,
   FormGroup, Input,
   Label, Row,
} from 'reactstrap';
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from 'react-google-places-autocomplete';
import {editInvoice, getInvoiceDetails} from "../../../helpers/api";


export default () => {

   //
   // var len = window.location.href.length;
   // var id = window.location.href[len-1];


   //TODO THIS IS NOT THE REACT METHOD TO FETCH ID FROM THE URLT

   const [form, setForm] = useState({
       'id': '',
       'invoice_number': '',
       'invoice_date': '',
       'invoice_due_date': '',
       'invoice_place_of_supply': '',
       'invoice_destination': '',
       'invoice_destination_address': '',
       'invoice_destination_pincode': '',
       'invoice_gst': '',


       'invoice_salesperson': '',
       'invoice_lr_number': '',
       'invoice_vehicle_placement_date': '',
       'invoice_vehicle_number': '',
       'invoice_service_month': '',
       'invoice_item_details': '',

       'invoice_rate': '',
       'invoice_tax': '',
       'invoice_amount': '',
       'invoice_quiz': '',
       'invoice_owner': '',
       'invoice_quantity': '',


       'lr_number': '',
       'billing_party_name': '',
       'origin_address': '',
       'origin_pincode': '',
       'vehicle_placement_date': '',
       'vehicle_number': '',
       'item_details': '',
       'item_quantity': '',
       'total_amount': '',
       'tax': '',

   });


   useEffect(() => {
       const getNetwork = async () => {
           const invoice_details = await getInvoiceDetails(form.id);
           setForm(invoice_details);
       };
       getNetwork();
   }, [setForm]);


   const handleInputChange = (event) => {
       const target = event.target;
       const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
       const name = target.name;

       setForm({
           ...form,
           [name]: value
       });
   };

   const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();
       try {
           alert(JSON.stringify(form));
           await editInvoice(form, form.id);
           alert('done')
       } catch (e) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(e))
       }
   };

   return (
       <Card>
           <CardHeader>
               <strong>Edit Invoice</strong>
           </CardHeader>
           <CardBody>
               <Form method={'post'} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                   <Row form>
                       <Col md={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="origin">Invoice number</Label>
                               <Input type="text" name="invoice_number" id="invoice_number" valid={form.invoice_number}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>

                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>

                       <Col md={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="origin">Invoice ID</Label>
                               <Input type="text" name="id" id="id" value={form.id}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>

                       </Col>
                       <Col md={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="scheduled_date">Invoice Date</Label>
                               <Input type="datetime-local" name="invoice_date" id="invoice_date"
                                      value={form.invoice_date}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                   </Row>

                   <Row>
                       <Col lg={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="truck_type">Invoice Due Date</Label>
                               <Input type="select" name="invoice_due_date" id="invoice_due_date"
                                      onChange={handleInputChange} valid={form.invoice_due_date}>

                               </Input>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                       <Col lg={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="total_trucks">Place of Supply</Label>
                               <Input type="number" name="invoice_place_of_supply" id="invoice_place_of_supply"
                                      value={form.invoice_place_of_supply}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>

                       <Col md={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="offered_price">Invoice Destination</Label>
                               <Input type="test" name="invoice_destination" id="invoice_destination"
                                      value={form.invoice_destination}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                   </Row>


                   <Row>
                       <Col lg={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="truck_type">Destination Address</Label>
                               <Input type="select" name="invoice_destination_address" id="invoice_destination_address"
                                      onChange={handleInputChange} value={form.invoice_destination_address}>

                               </Input>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                       <Col lg={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="total_trucks">Destination PINCODE</Label>
                               <Input type="number" name="invoice_destination_pincode" id="invoice_destination_pincode"
                                      value={form.invoice_destination_pincode}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>

                       <Col md={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="offered_price">Invoice GST</Label>
                               <Input type="number" name="invoice_gst" id="invoice_gst" value={form.invoice_gst}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                   </Row>

                   <Row>
                       <Col lg={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="truck_type">Billing party</Label>
                               <Input type="select" name="invoice_salesperson" id="invoice_salesperson"
                                      onChange={handleInputChange} value={form.invoice_salesperson}>

                               </Input>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                       <Col lg={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="total_trucks">LR number</Label>
                               <Input type="number" name="invoice_lr_number" id="invoice_lr_number"
                                      value={form.invoice_lr_number}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>

                       <Col md={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="offered_price">Vehicle Placement Date</Label>
                               <Input type="number" name="invoice_vehicle_placement_date"
                                      id="invoice_vehicle_placement_date" value={form.invoice_vehicle_placement_date}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                   </Row>
                   <Row>
                       <Col lg={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="truck_type">Vehicle Number</Label>
                               <Input type="select" name="invoice_vehicle_number" id="invoice_vehicle_number"
                                      onChange={handleInputChange} value={form.invoice_vehicle_number}>

                               </Input>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                       <Col lg={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="total_trucks">Invoice service Month</Label>
                               <Input type="number" name="invoice_service_month" id="invoice_service_month"
                                      value={form.invoice_service_month}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>

                       <Col md={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="offered_price">invoice Item Details</Label>
                               <Input type="text" name="invoice_item_details" id="invoice_item_details"
                                      value={form.invoice_item_details}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                   </Row>


                   <Row>
                       <Col lg={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="truck_type">Invoice Amount</Label>
                               <Input type="select" name="invoice_rate" id="invoice_rate" onChange={handleInputChange}
                                      value={form.invoice_rate}>

                               </Input>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                       <Col lg={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="total_trucks">TAX</Label>
                               <Input type="number" name="invoice_tax" id="invoice_tax" value={form.invoice_tax}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>

                       <Col md={4}>
                           <FormGroup>
                               <Label for="offered_price">Total Amount</Label>
                               <Input type="number" name="invoice_amount" id="invoice_amount"
                                      value={form.invoice_amount}
                                      onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                           </FormGroup>
                       </Col>
                   </Row>


                   <br/><br/><br/>
                   <Button color={"primary"} size={"lg"}>Create</Button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <Button color={"link"} size={"lg"}>Cancel</Button>
               </Form>
           </CardBody>
       </Card>
   )
}
```

This is my code from API.js :

```
const EDIT_INVOICE = 'api/invoice/<int:pk>/';

export const editInvoice = (data,id) => loadSecureUrl(`${EDIT_INVOICE}${id}`, {
    data: data,
    method: 'patch'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the string you're passing into the `loadSecureUrl` function is `'api/invoice/<int:pk/1'` if `id` is `1`. You rather want `'api/invoice/1/'` so change your api code to:

```
const EDIT_INVOICE_BASE = 'api/invoice/';

export const editInvoice = (data,id) => loadSecureUrl(`${EDIT_INVOICE_BASE}${id}/`, {
    data: data,
    method: 'patch'
});
```